# How can I compile an Apache Thrift definition file?

Tags: java, thrift

I'm trying to compile an Apache Thrift definition file (on Ubuntu). I keep getting the error message: `Could not open input file with realpath: Calculator.thrift` whenever I enter `thrift -r --gen java Calculator.thrift` into the command line. I have already installed Thrift. Where should I save .thrift definition files so that it will be possible to compile them?

Comment: I am referring to the following tutorial: http://1b1t.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/thrift-part-four-write-and-compile-a-thrift-file/

Comment: Also, what does "realpath" refer to in this case?

Comment: would it be possible to post your thrift def file?

Comment: Please do not use the Apache tag for topics other than the web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the tutorial directory that comes with the thrift installation, you should see the following 2 `*.thrift` files:

```
shared.thrift
tutorial.thrift
```

From this same directory you should be able to generate/compile from the thrift IDL files as follows:

```
thrift -r --gen java ./tutorial.thrift
```

This should create a `gen-java` sub-directory in the tutorial directory.

The `Calculator.thrift` file does not actually exist, the Calculator service is defined in `tutorial.thrift`. The error is trying to tell you that it cant find the file, and rightly so, since it doesnt actually exist :)

Comment: I navigated to the tutorials folder, ran the command `thrift -r --gen java tutorial.thrift`, and got the following output: `[FAILURE:arguments:1] Could not open input file with realpath: tutorial.thrift` What does this indicate?

Comment: I got this error even though I ran the command from the tutorials directory, which contains the `tutorial.thrift` file.

Comment: Actually, I was in the wrong directory. That explains why it didn't work. I moved to the correct directory, and all of the files were generated!

Comment: @AndersonGreen, glad to hear its working now. I updated the answer to specify where the IDL file is, just in case.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori your link automatically redirects to other web pages. Is this by design or have you lost control of your website since posting this? Do you have a new location for your tutorial?

Comment: @MrMas Sorry about that. I've changed my domain. Here's the new link: http://anoori.me/blog/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction