# Thrift gen error

Tags: python, thrift

I am trying to connect my python code to hive via thrift. Thrift is installed.

```
bash-3.2$ which thrift
/usr/local/bin/thrift
bash-3.2$ thrift -gen py tutorial.thrift
[FAILURE:arguments:1] Could not open input file with realpath: tutorial.thrift
```

Can some one help me how to fix this. My import thrift command on python will not work without this.

Comment: You probably checked this already: Is the tutorial.thrift file in the CWD (current working directory) or somewhere else? What does `ls *.thrift` say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I compile an Apache Thrift definition file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241306/how-can-i-compile-an-apache-thrift-definition-file)

Comment: In the tutorial folder there are files however, when I do a new one I get a warning. However, haxe is present. bash-3.2$ thrift --gen py:new_style ./shared.thrift
   [WARNING:/Users/taposh/workspace/thrift/thrift/tutorial/shared.thrift:30]          No generator named 'haxe' could be found!

Comment: As a general rule, the Thrift libs and tutorials should absolutely match the compiler version, because they depend on each other. Haxe will be supported starting with 0.9.3 which is not yet released. If you don't intend to target Haxe with Thrift, just continue with 0.9.2 and ignore the warning. If you want Haxe support today, you will have to build the Thrift compiler from trunk. It is there and it works (hxcpp), it is just not officially released yet.

Comment: have you tried an absolute path instead of the relative path ? do realpath tutorial.thrift (if the file is in the current directory) and call thrift with the answer as argument

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: 
Comment out the line starting with `namespace haxe` in *tutorial.thrift* and *shared.thrift*.

My guess is that my thrift binary (homebrew installed) is not built with haxe support.